# Executable path error in xcode 4.2

Tags: macos, xcode4.2

I am building a command line tool .I have added Flac.framework in my xcode project and I am running it for 32 bit mac. But It is giving error after running

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/FLAC.framework/Versions/A/FLAC
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flac_decoder-dbwsvotpcvjmwceheldbxndflbig/Build/Products/Debug/Flac_decoder
>   Reason: image not found

I have included Header search Path and framework path and still giving error. How to resolve this ?

Comment: Try once close your app and open again run